# Generating modopt using Reflection.Emit in Calli instruction

Tags: c#, .net, cil, reflection.emit

I'm trying to use Reflection.Emit to generate the code for `Call` method of following code:

```cs
public unsafe class Program
{
    public struct ATest
    {
        public int Test;
    }
    
    public struct Test
    {
        public Vtable* vtbl;
        
        public struct Vtable
        {
            public delegate * unmanaged[Stdcall]<Test*, ATest> ptr;
        }
    }
    
    public static ATest Call(Test* instance)
    {
        return ((delegate * unmanaged[Stdcall, MemberFunction]<Test*, ATest>)instance->vtbl->ptr)(instance);
    }
    
}
```

I've decompiled the method using [sharplab.io](//sharplab.io) and got following msil:

```
// Methods
.method public hidebysig static 
    valuetype Program/ATest Call (
        valuetype Program/Test* 'instance'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 25 (0x19)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] method unmanaged valuetype Program/ATest modopt([System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvMemberFunction) modopt([System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) *(valuetype Program/Test*),
        [1] valuetype Program/ATest
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldfld valuetype Program/Test/Vtable* Program/Test::vtbl
    IL_0007: ldfld method unmanaged stdcall valuetype Program/ATest *(valuetype Program/Test*) Program/Test/Vtable::ptr
    IL_000c: stloc.0
    IL_000d: ldarg.0
    IL_000e: ldloc.0
    IL_000f: calli unmanaged valuetype Program/ATest modopt([System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvMemberFunction) modopt([System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall)(valuetype Program/Test*)
    IL_0014: stloc.1
    IL_0015: br.s IL_0017

    IL_0017: ldloc.1
    IL_0018: ret
} // end of method Program::Call
```

I've tried to generete MSIL instructions using reflection.emit, but I don't know how to emit the line `IL_000f`:

```cs
var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, vtableField);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, methodField);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);

il.EmitCalli(???);
```

The issue is, that this line in MSIL has both `modopt(MemberFunction)` and `mopopt(Stdcall)`, and I do not see this exposed anywhere in `il.EmitCalli` method.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11354, it is not currently possible to use function pointers in reflection stack (`typeof(delegate* ...)` always returns `IntPtr` currently), so there is no way to make Reflection.Emit work reliably in this case.

Comment: One note for people who really need this, while it is not possible to do using `ILGenerator`, it should be possible (but much harder) to emit such method using raw msil bytes using `MethodBuilder.CreateMethodBody`